# What using statement do I need for the Transfer class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to create an instance of `Transfer` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.transfer.aspx in my code. I included a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` and I have `using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;` at the top and the namespace is recognized. However the `Transfer` class is not recognized:

```
var transfer = new Transfer(database);
```

gives the notorious

> The type or namespace ...

error.

Comment: Did you include required assembly (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll)?

Comment: You also need to add a reference to the assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended` in your project

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan No, and that fixed it. But how would I have been able to figure that out myself, I wonder.

Comment: @DeadlyNicotine See in the documentation. MSDN class documentation always mention assembly where class is reside.

Answer (score 0):

Run from **Nuget Package Manager Console**

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll
```

Add to your class:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
```

Hope this helps!